# why Convert and datetime doesnt work for datetime(2(0)

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Why neither of Convert or datetime string passing doesn't work for datetiem2(0) field here is the query.

```
 SELECT IsNull(Max(SOURCE_CODE), 'UNKNOWN') source_code,
 FROM  Table1
 WHERE   
 --DATE_INSERTED between CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/01/2013') AND  CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/31  /2013')
  DATE_INSERTED >='2013-10-10 00:00:01 AM'  AND DATE_INSERTED <= '2013-10-31                 23:59:59     PM'    
    AND   (SOURCE_CODE IS NOT NULL)  AND 
    (RESULT_CODE = 0  OR RESULT_CODE = 100)  GROUP BY SOURCE_CODE
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesnt work ? throwing an error if yes please can you show the ERROR MESSAGE you are getting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run `select convert(datetime, '10/01/2013')`, you're going to get `2013-10-10 00:00:01` every time.  So you're saying `between 2013-10-10 00:00:01 and 2013-10-10 00:00:01`.
Which probably isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT IsNull(Max(SOURCE_CODE), 'UNKNOWN') source_code,
 FROM  Table1
 WHERE   
 --DATE_INSERTED between CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/01/2013') AND  CONVERT(DATETIME,'10/31  /2013')
  DATE_INSERTED >='2013-10-10 00:00:01'  AND DATE_INSERTED <= '2013-10-31 23:59:59'    
    AND   (SOURCE_CODE IS NOT NULL)  AND 
    (RESULT_CODE = 0  OR RESULT_CODE = 100)  GROUP BY SOURCE_CODE
```

Since `Datetime2(0)` datatype stores values with no decimals in seconds and hours from `00:00:00 - 23:59:59` you adding **AM/PM** with passed values '2013-10-10 00:00:01 AM'  in your where condition filters out all the values in the result set and you get an empty set back. Try you query again without using AM/PM and it should work fine.
Using AM/PM will give you the following error

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```